# Error calling a procedure with tables owned by different breeds

Tags: netlogo

I would like to multiply the values of two different agent breeds with a function

```
to-report prod-val-tables [ inter popular ]
  let ans 0
  foreach (table:keys inter) [ [?] -> 
    set ans (ans + (table:get inter ?) * (table:get popular ?)) ]
  report ans
end
```

but when I call this function

```
prod-val-tables we-interest popularity
```

it gives me an error because `we-interest`and `popularity` are from different breeds.

How could I solve it? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your description of the error does not appear to be correct.  Please copy the exact error message.  (All of it.)

Comment: The exact message shows up in the code tab when changing to `interface`tab is, _You can't use POPULARITY in a turtle context, because POPULARITY is link-only_.

Comment: If you ask a turtle to run `prod-val-tables we-interest popularity`, it won't know how to find `popularity`.  You need to provide the second table (e.g., `[popularity] of one-of my-links`).

Btw: Links and turtles are different types, not different breeds.

Comment: Thank you very much. `let kk [we-interest] of walkers-here` before calling `prod-val-tables popularity kk` made the _trick_. This code pass `we-interest` to `prod-val-tables` into a list [ ] so I had included the line `foreach inter [ [?] -> set i ?]`and pass `i`to the second foreach instead `inter`table. Thank you.